# Inject guice-created object into other object

Tags: java, guice, modularity, discord-jda

I have created a modular system for my project which uses Guice for dependency injection. The modules are subclasses of the abstract `Module` class and are indexed by the Reflections library. These modules also have injected fields like a `Configuration` class and a `Manager` class. Each module can have listeners, commands or timers assigned to it, which can be created with an annotation (the module is specified in the annotation parameters). These objects are also indexed by Reflections and are loaded with the modules.

I want to be able to inject a module into a listener, command, timer or another Module using Guice, without creating a binding for every single module that I create. For example:

Module:

```java
public class RandomModule extends Module {

    @Override
    public void onLoad() {
        // Load the module
    }

}
```

Listener:

```java
@Listener(module = RandomModule.class) // An annotation for Reflections to index
public class RandomListener extends ListenerAdapter { // ListenerAdapter is a class from a library I am using

    @Inject
    private RandomModule randomModule; // Inject the module somehow

    // Rest of the listener...

}
```

The modules are loaded by a ModuleLoader class at startup, modules can also have dependencies on another module which ensures that those modules are loaded before the dependant module. Dependencies can be set using the `@Dependencies` and `@Dependency` annotations.

ModuleLoader:

```java
public class ModuleLoader {

    private final Injector injector;

    public ModuleLoader(Manager manager) {
        this.injector = Guice.createInjector(new DefaultModule(manager));
    }

    public void load() {
        // Sorting by dependencies happens here

        for (Class<? extends Module> moduleClass : sortedList) {
            Module module = injector.getInstance(moduleClass);

            logger.info("Loading module {}", moduleClass.getSimpleName());

            modules.put(moduleClass, module);

            // Run timers
            for (Class<?> timerClass : reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Timer.class)) {
                Timer annotation = timerClass.getAnnotation(Timer.class);
                if (annotation.module() != moduleClass || annotation.phase() != ModulePhase.LOAD) continue;

                if (!TimerTask.class.isAssignableFrom(timerClass)) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Timer " + timerClass + " has Timer annotation but doesn't extend TimerTask");
                }

                injector.injectMembers(timerClass);
                timer.schedule((TimerTask) injector.getInstance(timerClass), annotation.delay(), annotation.interval());
            }

            injector.injectMembers(moduleClass);

            module.onLoad();
        }
    }

    public void enable(JDA jda) { // JDA is also a class from a library I'm using
        CommandHandler.Builder handlerBuilder = new CommandHandler.Builder();

        for (Class<? extends Module> moduleClass : sortedList) {
            logger.info("Enabling module {}", moduleClass.getSimpleName());

            // Register commands
            for (Class<?> commandClass : reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Command.class)) {
                Command annotation = commandClass.getAnnotation(Command.class);
                if (annotation.module() != moduleClass) continue;

                injector.injectMembers(commandClass);
                handlerBuilder.addCommand(injector.getInstance(commandClass));
            }

            // Register listeners
            for (Class<?> listenerClass : reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Listener.class)) {
                Listener annotation = listenerClass.getAnnotation(Listener.class);
                if (annotation.module() != moduleClass) continue;

                if (!ListenerAdapter.class.isAssignableFrom(listenerClass)) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Listener " + listenerClass + " has Listener annotation but doesn't extend ListenerAdapter");
                }

                injector.injectMembers(listenerClass);
                jda.addEventListener(injector.getInstance(listenerClass));
            }

            // Run timers
            for (Class<?> timerClass : reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Timer.class)) {
                Timer annotation = timerClass.getAnnotation(Timer.class);
                if (annotation.module() != moduleClass || annotation.phase() != ModulePhase.ENABLE) continue;

                if (!TimerTask.class.isAssignableFrom(timerClass)) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Timer " + timerClass + " has Timer annotation but doesn't extend TimerTask");
                }

                injector.injectMembers(timerClass);
                timer.schedule((TimerTask) injector.getInstance(timerClass), annotation.delay(), annotation.interval());
            }

            Module module = modules.get(moduleClass);
            module.onEnable();
        }

        this.commandHandler = handlerBuilder.build();
    }

}
```

I also have a DefaultModule class which is a Guice module and contains some bindings I need.

DefaultModule:

```java
public class DefaultModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final Manager manager;

    public DefaultModule(Manager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(JDA.class).toProvider(botManager::getJda).in(Scopes.SINGLETON); // Another class from a library
        bind(Manager.class).toInstance(manager);
        bind(Configuration.class).toProvider(botManager::getConfiguration).in(Scopes.SINGLETON); // A custom configuration class which contains database credentials etc.
        bind(Database.class).toProvider(() -> manager.getModuleLoader().getModule(DatabaseModule.class).getDatabase()).in(Scopes.SINGLETON); // And a database class from a DatabaseModule. This works fine, but I don't want to do this for every single module I create.

        bindListener(Matchers.any(), new Slf4JTypeListener());
    }

}
```

I'm new to Guice, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Please tell me if you need more info, or if you have other additional questions.